# How to create exclusive or on Haskell and use it?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a function that tells what kind of triangle is based on the input on the length of the 3 sides.

```
triangle a b c 
 |a+b<c = error "Not a triangle" 
 |a==b ... a==c ... c==b = isosceles triangle
 |a==b && b==c = "equilateral triangle"
 |otherwise = "scalene triangle"
```

Since the Isosceles triangle only has two equal sides I cannot use or "||".

I created that function, but I don't know how I would use that as an operator.

```
exclusiveOR a b = (a||b)&& not(a&&b)
```

Comment: You need to apply the triangle inequality to all the pairs.

Comment: @dfeuer Depends on the spec/contract. Perhaps the inputs are guaranteed to be in ascending order.

Comment: @amalloy, in that case there'd be no need to check three equalities for isosceles; two would be sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

You can either use it prefix, or enclose it in backticks to make it infix:

```
| exclusiveOR foo bar = ...
| foo `exclusiveOR` bar = ...
```

By the way, there's an existing short name for this function.

```
| foo /= bar = ...
```

Comment: I've never seen that function, how do I use it?

Comment: @Heil `(condition1 /= condition2) /= condition3`. It's not that obvious at first that this is the XOR of three booleans. Consider a custom definition `xor = (/=)` to give it another name.

Comment: @Heil You use it like any other infix operator, exactly like the `(&&)` and `(||)` operators that you've already used. I also gave an example in my answer of how to use it.

Comment: @DanielWagner Note, however, that `a && b && c` is legal while `a /= b /= c` is not, since the fixity does not provide a direction to associate. Above I added parentheses to avoid the issue.

Comment: @Heil You almost certainly have seen that function before at some point. It means "not equal to" (sometimes written as `!=` or as `≠` elsewhere). You are just applying it to booleans in this specific scenario. Note a xor b is precisely true when a and b are not the same and false when a and b are the same.

Answer (score 6):

Just switch the order of the cases. Check `a==b && b==c` first; if that fails, then check `a==b || a==c || c==b`, and if that succeeds, the triangle *must* be isosceles (since you’ve already eliminated the equilateral case).

Comment: Agree that this is much preferrable, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Whoops, sorry! Obviously I didn’t read the question properly before answering.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Well, this looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): the OP asked a question which is not the one they should have asked to solve their actual issue. I think this addresses the actual issue, even if it does not address the question as asked, so it should be kept as an answer.